# Internet Explorer 11 Absolute Positioned Image Getting Dark Color

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a site where I need to have an image with the following css:

`postion: absolute;
 bottom: 50%;
 left: 0;`

It works fine for Safari, Chrome and Firefox. At the Internet Explorer 11 the positioning is also ok, however the image get a dark color over it.

I have been looking to understand the reason for that, but nothing so far.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Thanks,
João

Comment: can u add a screenshot?

Comment: Or, even better, a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. It is related with opacity in a related element. Thanks for your help!